# MonetDB - How to call .SQL files from within SQL files?

Tags: sql, monetdb

How can I run `.SQL` files from other `.SQL` files using **MonetDB**?

I went through the whole documentation but had no success finding it.

For instance, in `MySql` I could do something like

#### parent.sql

```
use mydatabase;
source child1.sql
source child2.sql
```

#### child1.sql

```
SELECT * from Products;
```

#### child2.sql

```
SELECT * from Orders;
```

How can I do that (or something similar) using `MonetDB`?

Comment: To dump the SQL database, start the MonetDB SQL Client program and type the command

\>...\databasedump.sql

Comment: Have you tried using the "\<child1.sql" instead of "source child1.sql" in your parent script?

Comment: @vmachan yes , but a syntax error is raised

Comment: Could you share the syntax error you get?

Answer (score 0):

To dump the SQL database, start the MonetDB SQL Client program and type the command

```
\>...\databasedump.sql
\D
\>
```

The path after > should be an absolute path name (i.e. start with a drive letter) and be in a save location. By default the database is located in  %APPDATA%\MonetDB5. After having made a database dump it can be removed. This folder is located inside the dbfarm\demofolder.

Restoring the SQL database can be done using the MonetDB SQL Client program with the following command

```
\<...\databasedump.sql
```

Source:
https://www.monetdb.org/Documentation/UserGuide/DumpRestore

Comment: Please update your question to have some more details

Comment: I don't know what else I could write. I guess its fine to understand. What you wrote works, but how do I call another SQL file from within the `databasedump.sql` that you mentioned?

Comment: The path after \> should be an absolute path name (i.e. start with a drive letter) and be in a save location. By default the database is located in  %APPDATA%\MonetDB5. After having made a database dump it can be removed. This folder is located inside the dbfarm\demofolder.